# How to run HBase program

Tags: hadoop, hbase

How can I run the code below from the command line?

```
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.*;

public class MyHBase {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Configuration conf = HBaseConfiguration.create();
        HBaseAdmin admin = new HBaseAdmin(conf);
        try {
            HTable table = new HTable(conf, "test-table");
            Put put = new Put(Bytes.toBytes("test-key"));
            put.add(Bytes.toBytes("cf"), Bytes.toBytes("q"), Bytes.toBytes("value"));
            table.put(put);
        } finally {
            admin.close();
        }
    }
}
```

How to set my hbase classpath? I am getting a huge string in my classpath.

UPDATE

```
root# vi MyHBase.java 
hbase-0.92.2 root# java -classpath `hbase classpath`:./ /var/root/MyHBase
-sh: hbase: command not found
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: /var/root/MyHBase
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: .var.root.MyHBase
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
```

I am able to do

```
hbase-0.92.2 root# bin/hbase shell
HBase Shell; enter 'help<RETURN>' for list of supported commands.
Type "exit<RETURN>" to leave the HBase Shell
Version 0.92.2, r1379292, Fri Aug 31 13:13:53 UTC 2012

hbase(main):001:0> exit
```

Am i doing anything wrong?

Comment: HBase has a lot of dependencies, it's going to be a long string.

Comment: `java -classpath` doe not work?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can also do something like this:-

```
# export HADOOP_CLASSPATH=`./hbase classpath`
```

and then bundle this java in jar to run it within hadoop cluster like this:-

```
#hadoop jar <jarfile> <mainclass>
```

Answer (score 5):

Use this

```
java -classpath `hbase classpath`:./ MyHBase
```

this will get the entire classpath string that HBase uses and adds the current directory as well to the classpath.

Cheers
Rags

Comment: You cannot execute a class like this. The path where the class file is present needs to be on the classpath. Execute the same command from the directory where the class file is present. Alternately you add /var/root to the classpath.

Comment: I tried  javac -cp `hbase classpath` MyHBase.java 
     java -cp `hbase classpath` MyHBase bt not working. Showing  hbase: command not found

Comment: should i set classpath in hbase-env

Comment: You mean java command not found? Please share entire error with me. I see that you were able to execute java command earlier!------------- Check couple of more things. Are you able to execute hbase command from anywhere? Add hbase bin directory to your PATH.

Comment: Then add hbase/bin to your path. Make sure that you are able to execuet hbase command from anywhere.

Comment: No. To the PATH environment variable.

Comment: For example if your java in installed under/usr/java/j2sdk1.4.2, you will enhance your PATH variable as PATH=$PATH:/usr/java/j2sdk1.4.2/bin.  You need to export this. So run the command `export PATH=$PATH:/usr/java/j2sdk1.4.2/bin`.   You need to do similarly for Hbase as well